# regex split string with two separators

Tags: javascript, regex, split, match, separator

Using JavaScript, Is there a way to split the string to an array with two separators: ':' and ','

For var str = "21:223, 310:320";

would like the Result to be: [21, 223, 310, 320];

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression which looks for a `:` or for a comma with an optional space `,`.

```js
console.log("21:223, 310:320,42".split(/:|, */));
```

Comment: Hi the above works for comma with space after that. Do you know how can I add separator for comma without a space after that ?

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` if your expression is like this `"21:223, 310:320"`

```js
var str = "21 :  223 , 310 :  320 ";
//---------^^----^^^---^^^----^^^--
// group of digits(represented by ^) will be matched
console.log(str.match(/(\d+)/g));
// will return ["21", "223", "310", "320"]
```

Comment: Thanks @suraj.tripathi!